# How to set text to show currency on tooltip (using plot_ly NOT ggplotly)?

Tags: r, plot, plotly, r-plotly

As far as I could investigate a need to set the "text" argument when generating the plotly object, and then call this "text" argument as the tooltip.

**data:**

```
ha <- structure(list(periodo = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2017", 
"2016"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), ecommerce = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("falabella", "ripley", "linio"
), class = c("ordered", "factor")), marca = c("samsung", "samsung", 
"lg", "lg", "samsung", "lg"), producto = c("samsung tv led hd 32'' 32j4000", 
"samsung smart tv led fhd 48\"\" 3d 48j6400", "lg smart tv led 43'' full hd 43lh5700", 
"lg smart tv led 49'' full hd 49lh5700", "samsung smart tv 50ju6500 led uhd 50\"\" - negro", 
"lg smart tv led 49\"\" ultra hd tv 49uh6500"), precio.antes = c(999, 
2799, 1649, 1999, 3699, 2799), precio.actual = c(799, 1999, 1249, 
1699, 2399, 2199), pulgadas = c(32, 48, 43, 49, 50, 49), rango = c("S/.500 -\r\n S/.1500", 
"S/.1500 -\r\n S/.2500", "S/.500 -\r\n S/.1500", "S/.1500 -\r\n S/.2500", 
"S/.1500 -\r\n S/.2500", "S/.1500 -\r\n S/.2500"), descuento = c(-0.2002002002002, 
-0.285816362986781, -0.242571255306246, -0.150075037518759, -0.351446336847797, 
-0.214362272240086)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

In ggplotly the text argument is placed inside the `aes()` function.

When using plot_ly I'm placing it inside here:

```
p <- plot_ly(ha, x = ~periodo, y = ~precio.actual, color = ~ecommerce,colors = c("#BED800", "#802D69", "#FF5500"), text = sprintf("S/ %s", comma(~precio.actual)), textinfo= "text", hoverinfo = "text") %>%
  add_boxplot() %>%
  layout(boxmode = "group") %>% 
  config(displayModeBar = FALSE) 

p
```

**The code above has no effect on formatting the tooltip.**

Shows the tooltip but without the currency formatting needed.
Instead of 2399, it should be S/ 2,399, for example.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format the y variable in `layout` by passing a list with `hoverformat`, which takes a formatting string like `sprintf`.

```r
plot_ly(ha, x = ~periodo, y = ~precio.actual, color = ~ecommerce, 
        colors = c("#BED800", "#802D69", "#FF5500")) %>%
    add_boxplot() %>%
    layout(yaxis = list(
        hoverformat = '$,.2f'
    )) %>% 
    config(displayModeBar = FALSE)
```

[image: plotply plot with formatted hoverinfo]

If you want to get fancier, you can use `hovertemplate`. There are lots of examples here: https://plot.ly/r/hover-text-and-formatting/

Comment: it only works with dolar symbol `$`, not with `S/`, `S`, `\\S` or `\\S\\/`.  May you tried these symbol: `S/` as the currency format?